# How can I call MigrateDbContext in startup of Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I need to call MigrateDbContext on the start up of my Azure function

Is there a way that I can call this on my overall function app startup?

If I inject the ServiceProvider into my function it does work and will migrate the database, but this is not a good approach because it means for every single call to my function I am trying to migrate the database which is not efficient

```
    public class MyFunctionApp
    {
        
        public MyFunctionApp(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .CreateLogger();

            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

            serviceProvider.MigrateDbContext<MyContext>((context, services) => { });
        }
    }
```

I have a Function start up file

However, I dont have access to IServiceProvider here

```
public abstract class MyFunctionStartup: FunctionsStartup
{
    public IConfigurationRefresher ConfigurationRefresher { get; private set; }
    
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        
    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: why not making the migration as part of the release process?

Comment: That is a long term goal but not an option at the moment